# Python - Check if file exists from yesterday

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that checks if a file exists from the day before. In this instance, I am trying to establish if the file "myFile_20180306" exists with the C:\myFolder\ directory.

The issue I am having is that in the for loop it prints "ERROR: myFile_20180306 does not exist!" multiple times in the console.

How do I re-write this script to display the print line only once if the file exists or not?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
yesterdaysDate = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
yesterdaysFile_myFile = yesterday.strftime('myFile_%Y%m%d.csv')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\myFolder'):
    for file in files:
        if file == yesterdaysFile_myFile:
            print 'OKAY: ',yesterdaysFile_myFile,' is available.'   
        else:
            print 'ERROR: ',yesterdaysFile_myFile,' does not exist!'
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: there isn't a question here! btw, your format does not match the example filename

Comment: What is the issue with the for and if statement?

Comment: apologies! Updated the "question" :-)

Comment: For each individual file you're determining whether your file exists or not. So, if the one file you're currently looking at is not your searched file, you generally declare that your file does not exist at all. Your logic needs to be to declare the file found when you found it, and only after you have exhausted the loop *without finding your file* you declare that the file does not exist. Hint: `found = False`, …, `if ...: found = True`.

Comment: @deceze with edits this question is probably clear now

Answer (score 1):

Kieran,

Thanks for clarifying your question. As noted in comments, your issue with your loop is that for EACH file in the directory your code will print either the ok or the error message depending on which is applicable to that file. Presumably it will mostly be errors.

Consider this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
yesterdaysDate = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
yesterdaysFile_myFile = yesterday.strftime('myFile_%Y%m%d.csv')

file_names = os.listdir('C:\myFolder')
if yesterdaysFile_myFile in file_names:
    print("OKAY: {0} is available".format(yesterdaysFile_myFile))
else:
    print('ERROR: {0} does not exist!".format(yesterdaysFile_myFile))
```

os.listdir() provides you a list of all the file/directory names in a directory. You can then check to see if your desired element is in the list without doing a second loop -- this is both more efficient for the process and less total code.

Based on if your element is in the list or not, you display the correct message.

Hope this helps